# How do I get the last record from sql server?

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic

I have my table "Billet" with :
- BilletID (int)
- commentaire(text)

I want to get the last record "commentaire" and display it in the Label in ASP.NET.

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? An SQL query or ASP code or...?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: this link might help you  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008 and I'm looking for the sql query and a asp code to get the last record from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 commentaire
from billet
order by billetid desc
```

above SQL query get last record from your billet table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select commentaire
from billet
order by billetid desc
limit 1
```

Order by the `billetid` and get only one record. This is different for the specific Db engine you use. MySQL uses `limit 1`. MSSQL uses `select top 1 ...` and Oracle `where rownum <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
select commentaire
from billet
order by billetid desc
limit 1;
```